# Fill textbox from excel spreadsheet

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am trying to populate textbox fields from an excel sheet using vb.net.

I have the following code:

```
  <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" 
            Height="21px" Text="Upload" 
            Width="92px" onclick="btnUpload_Click"/>
</div>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

Using the Fileupload a user can upload an excel sheet, Which will then extract the information to populate some fields.

My first step is trying to get it to databind with the grid view on button click to which I am having no luck: Using the following:

```
 Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim connectionString As String = ""
    If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
        Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
        Dim fileExtension As String = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
        Dim fileLocation As String = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" & fileName)
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileLocation)

        'Check whether file extension is xls or xslx

        If fileExtension = ".xls" Then
            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & fileLocation & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2"""
        ElseIf fileExtension = ".xlsx" Then
            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & fileLocation & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2"""
        End If

        'Create OleDB Connection and OleDb Command

        Dim con As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand()
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = con
        Dim dAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dtExcelRecords As New DataTable()
        con.Open()
        Dim dtExcelSheetName As DataTable = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
        Dim getExcelSheetName As String = dtExcelSheetName.Rows(0)("Table_Name").ToString()
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" & getExcelSheetName & "]"
        dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd
        dAdapter.Fill(dtExcelRecords)
        con.Close()
        GridView1.DataSource = dtExcelRecords
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

To which I am getting the error "Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Portal\docs\Encoding_Time.csv' is denied.
", which makes me ask where does the file upload control save the file?

UPDATE: I am now getting the following error "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized."

Comment: I'd guess that error would happen if the file extension was neither xls or xlsx. If that's all you want to accept, you should probably return an error condition if the file doesn't match either of them, instead of just carrying on regardless.

Comment: You must make sure that the account INETUSR? (I think thats what its called not sure if its IISUSER? ) has access to read on the folder docs otherwise access will be denied. The connectionstring error could be happening because the file extensions was neither xls or xlsx as ADyson mentions above...

Comment: There are better ways to deal with Excel files.